# Outlook add reference from file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created a macro in Outlook which needs Word and Excel references. It has to work on different versions of Office (2007, 2010, 2013). I have Office 2013, so when I "install" macro (copy VBAProject.otm) on 2007 and 2010 I have missing references. I wanted to add references manually using code similar to this in Excel:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile
```

but I couldn't find anything like that. I searched internet, but I also failed.
Can anyone tell me if in Outlook VBA is possible to add reference from file?

Answer (score 1):

To use unreferenced libraries and avoid setting references on each users' computer you access them by creating objects via [late binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/245115). This is typically done using the CreateObject method e.g for the scripting runtime you'd use:

```
Dim fso as object

Set fso = CreateObject("Microsoft.ScriptingRuntime")
```

You can search online for how to late bind the particular reference you require.

Comment: More specifically and to the point, for Outlook, it would be `Set OLApp  = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").`

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I thought a broad answer would be suitable as it's a big area to study if you don't know about early/late binding.

Comment: Nah, it'd be `Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` or  `Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` if Excel's already running - code is in Outlook, so no need for Outlook references.  Upvoted anyway - it's about the early/late binding that needs looking into.

Comment: Yes, but when I turn off Excel reference then code below is not working:
`xlSheet.Range("B1:I" & row).Sort Key1:=xlSheet.Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal`

Comment: @ dexter910 did you set an Excel reference in code like we suggested? Post your current code. What error did you get, if any?

Comment: Here is my code:
`Dim xlapp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set xlWB = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets(1)
Const xlUp As Long = -4162
row = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
xlSheet.Range("A" & row) = TextBox2.Text
xlSheet.Range("A1:A" & row).Sort Key1:=xlSheet.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _DataOption1:=xlSortNormal`

Comment: I don't know if there is any way to write this code in separeted lines

Comment: Sorry, there is error, when I want to sort rows: vba runtime error 1004 sort method of range class failed

Comment: @ dexter910 which line do you get the error on? What is the value of your row variable and do you use the Sort.Apply method in your sort?

Comment: `Const xlUp As Long = -4162
 row = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row`. I didn't use apply method. With Excel reference there was no need for that. I solved problem when I used this code: 'xlSheet.Range("B2:I" & row).Sort Key1:=xlSheet.Range("B1"), Order1:=1'